# How to define a module and use it to separate js files

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have an HTML file performing a Query Task on the feature layer of a webmap.

Now I want to separate the file into 3 different files: html file, a main.js file which loads the webmap, and a Color-Code.js file which performs the Query task and the rest. Basically, the html file should call main.js which in turn should call the Color_Code.js.I tried it with require.js... but I get a file Color-Code.js not found error every time.  I am really new to dojo and arcGIS , so could someone point out where am I going wrong.

```
Main.js -> require([
            "Color-Extent",
            "dojo/parser",
            "esri/arcgis/utils",
            "esri/map",
            "esri/dijit/Legend",
            "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
            ColorExtent,
            parser,
            arcgisUtils,
            Map,
            Legend
          ) {
    parser.parse();
    return {
        createMap: function () {
            arcgisUtils.createMap("ce88f9dba8d748a4bf3aa8d6c8027d2e ", "map").then(function (response) {
                var map = response.map;

                var legend = new Legend({
                    map: map,
                    layerInfos: (arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response))
                }, "legendDiv");
                legend.startup();
            });
            return map;
            ColorExtent.colorCurrentExtent();
        }
    }           
        });


Color-Code.js -> 

define([        "Main",
                "dojo/parser",
                "esri/arcgis/utils",
                "esri/map",
                "esri/dijit/Legend",
                "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
                "esri/tasks/query",
                "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
                "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
                "esri/Color",
                "dojo/_base/json",
                "dojo/text!./jdata.txt",
                "esri/geometry/Extent",
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
                "esri/graphic",
                "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (
                main,
                parser,
                arcgisUtils,
                Map,
                Legend,
                QueryTask,
                Query,
                SimpleMarkerSymbol,
                SimpleLineSymbol,
                Color,
                json,
                JData,
                Extent,
                array,
                GraphicsLayer,
                Graphic
            ) {
            function colorCurrentExtent() {
                parser.parse();
                map.on("load", function () {
                    var map = main.createMap();
                    var queryTask = new QueryTask(featureLayer.url);
                    var query = new Query();
                    query.outFields = ["OBJECTID"];
                    query.returnGeometry = true;
                    query.where = "1=1";
                    queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
                })

                function showResults(featureSet) {
                    var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
                    symbol.setSize(20);
                    var resultFeatures = featureSet.features;
                    var storeobj = dojo.fromJson(JData);

                    map.on("extent-change", function () {
                        var extent = map.extent;
                        graphiclayer.clear();
                        //var extent = map.geographicExtent;                         
                        array.forEach(resultFeatures, function (feature) {
                            if (extent.contains(feature.geometry)) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                                    if (feature.attributes.OBJECTID === storeobj[0].data[i].assetID) {
                                        switch (storeobj[0].data[i].colorCode) {
                                            case 1:
                                                symbol.setColor(new Color([0, 255, 0, 0.75]));
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                symbol.setColor(new Color([255, 165, 0, 0.75]));
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                symbol.setColor(new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.75]));
                                                break;
                                            case 4:
                                                symbol.setColor(new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.75]));
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                symbol.setColor(new Color([128, 128, 128, 0.75]));
                                                break;
                                        } // end switch
                                        graphiclayer.add(new Graphic(feature.geometry, symbol));
                                        break;
                                    } //end if
                                } // end for

                            } //end if
                        }) // end forEach
                    }) // end extent-change
                } // end showResults
                map.addLayer(graphiclayer);
            } //colorCurrentExtent
    });  and
```

I am referencing them in the html page as

```
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
    <script data-main="Main" src="require.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The results should do it: https://www.google.de/search?q=require+js+basic+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=GSc3V_OzEYvxUsDDlcgE#q=require+js+multiple+files

1st and second one. Maybe look for a basic requireJS tutorial explaining requireJS-module-definitions.

First of all separate files. Then Call in each file

```
require(["modules", "needed", "for", "THIS", "file"], function(a,b,c,d,e) {
   /*code goes here*/
   return Module;  
});
```

Hope it helps a bit.

Good tutorial I think: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/

Comment: I tried following what was outlined in the tutorial but obviously somethings went very very wrong. I have edited my question with the changes I made, perhaps you could help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some configuration to be done. As by default if you require module "Main", loader append baseUrl to it and trying to load it. I suggest [this tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/) for more undrestanding.

Answer (score 0):

What is link for require.js for?

require JS is already part of ESRI API. you dont need to include that explicitly. If you are adding the links to your custom modules, then make sure you add them after esri api. That way require will not give error.

Also in the function colorCurrentExtent() you are setting map load event and within that you are creating the instance of map. Which I think will not work as the map is not created when the event is initialized. move the line below outside the event.

```
 var map = main.createMap();
```

Also how is the colorCurrentExtent function called?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a couple of things.

1. The Esri JS API comes with a module loader from Dojo which works with AMD modules, so you do not need to load requirejs.
2. You seem to be missing the dojoConfig variable or have not posted it, this tells the AMD loader where to find your local modules. I recommend reading this tutorial for ArcGIS.  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-mapview/index.html.  It still may be good to read a requirejs/dojo AMD tutorial if your unsure how modules work.
3. Looks like Main.js depends on Color-Code.js which depends on Main.js, this circular dependency will cause issues.

I am trying to include a basic example below but I would definitely recommend looking at the Esri tutorials to help get you started.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var base = location.href.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '');
      var dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: false,
        async: true,
        packages: [
          { name: 'js', location: base + '/js' }
        ],
      deps: ['js/Main', 'dojo/domReady!'],
      callback: function (Main) { Main.createMap(); }
  };
    </script>
    <script src='//js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

dojo/domReady! fires when the dom is ready, surprise, and Main.js is loaded, then we launch our app by calling Main.createMap.  You can configure this path to your `js` folder under the packages property in the `dojoConfig` variable. That needs to be present and configured before you load the js api.

Main.js

```
define([
  "js/Color-Code",
  "dojo/parser",
  ... // remaining dependencies
], function (ColorCode, parser) {
  parser.parse();

  return {
    createMap: function () { ... }
  };
});
```

Color-Code.js

```
define([
  // Dependencies of the Color-Code.js Module only go here, e,g, you don't need the parser again
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView"
], function (Map, MapView) {

// Return the interface to the Color-Code file, either an object, function, class, etc.
  return {
    colorCurrentExtent: function () { ... }
  };

});
```

NOTE: This example is using modules and files from the 4.0 API, not the 3.16, but the setup part is the same.  And I would still recommend using @dazlious linked tutorials to make sure you have a good understanding of how modules work and what are some good design patterns to follow.